# indices of repeated string in list of strings

Tags: vb.net

what is my input ?
i have a data table , as below

```
keystring   date    order_number changetobedone-1 changetobedone-2
abc        11/19/20   O1234             12345          1789
abc-1      11/19/20   O1234             12345          1789
abc-2      11/19/20   O1234             12345          1789
abc        11/19/20   O1234             12345          1789
```

i need an array list  which consist of a **string ,  Array of dictionary of (string , string) , Array of integer**. out of this data table
what needs to be there in the dictionary ?

in this array of dictionary we must have string as the **unique keystring** and array of dictionary is nothing but set of all  column name value collection on which the key string appears.
and string , is the key string what we see. which appears in multiple rows.
and array of integer can be "0"  ALways. once i convert and pass this data at the receving end i will use this integer array and fill required numbers

in our example i need something like this as follows as result .
[image]

what i have done .

as it is evident the hardest part is the preparation of hte array of dictionary for every  unique keystring list
what i have done is using Linq i have just been able to pull the key string the number of times it appears. after making the list of all keystrings from the datatable
clearly what i need is more than that.  i need interact withthe data table directly and do this.
any one can guide me how to do ?

```
TempStrListKeyString.[Select](Function(x, i) New With {i, x}).GroupBy(Function(x) x.x).Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1).ToDictionary(Function(g) g.Key, Function(g) g.[Select](Function(x) x.i).ToList())
```

Comment: Why ArrayList? Use generics. And I would also go with a proper class design instead of nested dictionaries etc. What is the goal of the data? Show on a UI?

Comment: well thanks for giving comment , am not sure when you say generics. and this piece of code comes as a part of a ui automtion done by Uipath which is a .net framework based tool. so designing class and stuffs may be very tedious. to beging with the code is going to run inside uipath's "invoke code functionality. and i dont have a visual studio either. @AlexB.

Comment: i chose array list as we deal with three different data structure to store in one .
string , aray of dict(string, string) , array of int

Comment: With generics I mean a List(Of ...) or similar. At least the date, order_number, chagentobedone-1/-2 part should be put into a data record object. I don´t know Uipath but I`m sure you can use objects with it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks for answering. i understand it will be good to create a class and a method/constructor to do the job. but unfortunately the tool i have does not allow me to create classes. if i had create i should go for some tool like visual studio publish a DLL project then add the reference etc.,  thats why am looking for a modular solution. with mininal code , we can Use Linqs

Comment: @AlexB.instead of dictionary (string, string) it can be dict(string,object) thats ok. i agree on that and that can be done.

Comment: and one more reason for using Arraylist is , this needs to go in to something called "Queues" in the uipath tool. that will accept  only json schema.
with array list i can easily serialize and push  and reserialize  at the  receiving end . the other data types also can be Deserailised-easilty. like aray of dictionary , stirng list of integer etc.,

Comment: If you don´t get a proper answer here I would encourage you to ask it at he Uipath community if they have a forum